# Minimal Android SDK

Tags: android, sdk

I guess I can find out by trial and error but someone else has probably already figured it out. What Android SDK files are required to build an Android project? I don't need the rest and like to strip those away.

Comment: @Haphazard Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

You can safely delete 0.5 GB of documentation if you never use any of it. You can also make sure to only install the Android SDK version 2.3.x, but you need to be careful to not delete SDK's that newer SDK's depend on. The SDK manager is a useful tool for deleting unnecessary files.