# Android SDK minimal set for running apk

Tags: android

Similar to [Minimal Android SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6020797/minimal-android-sdk) for development.

**What is minimum set required for running .apk in Emulator?** (I need to prepare lightest zip for apk testers) And is there a way to make script for it's preparation.

I got the latest SDK `installer_r22.3-windows.exe` from [Get the Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html)

I guess it is like (+ USB driver):

[image: SDK mananger]

`tools\android.bat list sdk` will produce output:

```
Packages available for installation or update: 72
   1- Android SDK Platform-tools, revision 19.0.1
   2- Android SDK Build-tools, revision 19.0.1
   3- Documentation for Android SDK, API 19, revision 2
   4- SDK Platform Android 4.4.2, API 19, revision 2
   5- SDK Platform Android 4.3, API 18, revision 2
   6- SDK Platform Android 4.2.2, API 17, revision 2
   7- SDK Platform Android 4.1.2, API 16, revision 4
   8- SDK Platform Android 4.0.3, API 15, revision 3
   9- SDK Platform Android 4.0, API 14, revision 3
  10- SDK Platform Android 3.2, API 13, revision 1
  11- SDK Platform Android 3.1, API 12, revision 3
  12- SDK Platform Android 3.0, API 11, revision 2
  13- SDK Platform Android 2.3.3, API 10, revision 2
  14- SDK Platform Android 2.2, API 8, revision 3
  15- SDK Platform Android 2.1, API 7, revision 3
  16- SDK Platform Android 1.6, API 4, revision 3
  17- SDK Platform Android 1.5, API 3, revision 4
  18- Samples for SDK API 19, revision 3
  19- Samples for SDK API 18, revision 1
  20- Samples for SDK API 17, revision 1
  21- Samples for SDK API 16, revision 1
  22- Samples for SDK API 15, revision 2
  23- Samples for SDK API 14, revision 2
  24- Samples for SDK API 13, revision 1
  25- Samples for SDK API 12, revision 1
  26- Samples for SDK API 11, revision 1
  27- Samples for SDK API 10, revision 1
  28- Samples for SDK API 8, revision 1
  29- Samples for SDK API 7, revision 1
  30- ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android API 19, revision 2
  31- Intel x86 Atom System Image, Android API 19, revision 1
  32- ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android API 18, revision 2
  33- Intel x86 Atom System Image, Android API 18, revision 1
  34- ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android API 17, revision 2
  35- Intel x86 Atom System Image, Android API 17, revision 1
  36- MIPS System Image, Android API 17, revision 1
  37- ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android API 16, revision 3
  38- Intel x86 Atom System Image, Android API 16, revision 1
  39- MIPS System Image, Android API 16, revision 4
  40- ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android API 15, revision 2
  41- Intel x86 Atom System Image, Android API 15, revision 1
  42- MIPS System Image, Android API 15, revision 1
  43- ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android API 14, revision 2
  44- Intel x86 Atom System Image, Android API 10, revision 2
  45- Google APIs, Android API 19, revision 2
  46- Google APIs, Android API 18, revision 3
  47- Google APIs, Android API 17, revision 3
  48- Google APIs, Android API 16, revision 3
  49- Google APIs, Android API 15, revision 2
  50- Glass Development Kit Sneak Peek, Android API 15, revision 2
  51- Google APIs, Android API 14, revision 2
  52- Google APIs, Android API 13, revision 1
  53- Google TV Addon, Android API 13, revision 1
  54- Google APIs, Android API 12, revision 1
  55- Google APIs, Android API 11, revision 1
  56- Google APIs, Android API 10, revision 2
  57- Google APIs, Android API 8, revision 2
  58- Google APIs, Android API 7, revision 1
  59- Google APIs, Android API 4, revision 2
  60- Google APIs, Android API 3, revision 3
  61- Android Support Repository, revision 4
  62- Android Support Library, revision 19
  63- Google Analytics App Tracking SDK, revision 3
  64- Google Play services for Froyo, revision 12
  65- Google Play services, revision 14
  66- Google Repository, revision 5
  67- Google Play APK Expansion Library, revision 3
  68- Google Play Billing Library, revision 5
  69- Google Play Licensing Library, revision 2
  70- Google USB Driver, revision 9
  71- Google Web Driver, revision 2
  72- Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM), revision 3
```

Comment: You don't need any of those for _running_ an apk.

Comment: Please give an answer what is actually needed. As you see latest SDK has only SDK tools.

Comment: Why will apk testers need the sdk?

Comment: Yes, but why? I would not recommend _apk_ testers to test on an Emulator, and you won't need any of those for testing the apk on a real device.

Comment: You can simply email the APK or distribute from a web server with the appropriate mime type setting.  Granted, they will need to enable unknown sources, but to use the SDK they'd need to enable the developer menu and then USB debugging.  There are least was a time when you could put something on the Android Market and not expose it to searching, such that it could only be obtained via a link - not sure if that remains on the current Google Play but it's worth considering.  You could even distribute something that won't do anything until a tester access code is manually entered.

Comment: Updated Question: What is minimum set required for running .apk in Emulator? This question is about how to configure SDK, not about how to run .apk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need the platform-tools (android, emulator-*) to create AVDs and launch them in the emulator, the SDK tools (adb) to install your APK in the virtual device, and of course whatever system images you want the APK to be tested against (at least one of them).

It think it would be much easier for everyone if they used the SDK manager to download whatever they need than to pass them a subset of the tools in a zip file, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can install [Genymotion](http://www.genymotion.com/) emulator and do not install Android SDK at all.
The only thing you may need sdk for is to install an apk to device via `adb`. But you can install an apk without adb: for example, you can send an apk to email, open your email account from the device, open an apk - it'll be installed and here you go.

Comment: This is not answer what subset of SDK is needed. There are actually several alternatives to SDK http://www.nodeclipse.org/android/windows/pc/run/test/2014/03/04/Android-on-PC.html